# Vulkan vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR fails to load

Tags: c++, vulkan

Hey I'm trying to create a Windows Surface with Vulkan
but the somehow `vkGetInstanceProcAddr` fails to load the `vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR` function even though the extension is loaded properly.

Edit:
here I try to get the function pointer:

```
vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR =
(PFN_vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR)vkGetInstanceProcAddr(vulkanInstance.instance, 
"vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR");
```

Comment: Thanks for the question. You might try adding a little more detail of what you tried in the code to get a more helpful answer. Good luck!

Comment: what details do you need? I added the call to get the function pointer

Comment: I think your edit was good. Just trying to provide some helpful feedback on your first SO question post. I admit I'm not a subject matter expert on Vulkan. In general, if you ask the question in such a way that someone reading it could say, "I have that problem too! And hey I also tried what this guy tried!" Then you're doing well :) I will +1 the question because you show clear research effort by adding the call to get the function pointer. Happy Stack Overflowing!

Comment: Also, you may consider upvoting Sascha's answer since you marked it as the correct answer to your question. It's not required. Most important is that you marked it accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you enable the appropriate extension using e.g. the const `VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME` at instance creation time?

Also note that you don't need to manually get the function pointer for `vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR` unless you define `VK_NO_PROTOTYPES` as it's part of the core.

If you have enabled the extension and still don't get a valid function pointer, check if your drivers are properly installed, esp. that there is no old ICD registered that may cause problems. The LunarG Vulkan SDK contains a tool called "via" (in the bin folder) to check your Vulkan installation.

Comment: as I said the extension is loaded and the cube demo works as well so the drivers should be okay.
Okay I just tried it without loading the function manually and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: how do I know which function I have to load? Because for example the debug report callback functions I had to load even without the VK_NO_PROTOTYPES define

Comment: @ErikSimon (For official loader) you need to load any commands that are not core nor WSI.

Comment: I was mistakenly loading vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR with vkGetInstanceProcAddr and that was causing the call the fail silently, now that I call vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR directly everything works correctly. Therefore not only don't you have to get the function pointer dynamically, you really shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're okay using the C++ API instead of the C one, an easier way to do this is via the `vulkan.hpp` file that ships in the SDK.

You can `#define VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR` and `vk::Instance` will have a `vk::Result createWin32SurfaceKHR(vk::Win32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR*, vk::AllocationCallbacks*, vk::SurfaceKHR*)` member function. This helps alleviate the need for grabbing function pointers yourself.

Comment: is there any downside using the C++ API?

Answer (score 0):

Did you `#include` the `vulkan_win32.h` header in your source file?

`PFN_vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR` comes from an extension and so it is not defined in the core vulkan headers.

Answer (score 0):

On this... if you receive an error with the call to vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR, make sure you defined the sType on the VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR structure... Even though it's an VkWin32SurfaceCreateInfoKHR struct, forgetting stype is enough to make it fail.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with the same problem and found another cause.

vkCreateInstance takes a list of extensions

vkCreateDevice ALSO takes a list of extensions to enable

vkCreateWin32SurfaceKHR MUST be called to create the surface used by vkCreateDevice.

I was adding VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME for vkCreateDevice NOT vkCreateInstance.

Moving the declaration to the right place resolved the issue.